# How to edit the limit of attempts to change a password in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-cognito, change-password

I have implemented a change password feature and now I would like to test it. But I’m facing the limit of attempts.
What should I do to prevent this error?

> Attempt limit exceeded, please try after some time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am on the Cognito team. This is not configurable. We do have protection mechanisms to prevent users from abusing forgot password APIs which is probably what you are witnessing.

Comment: I am developing my app, part of this is testing my failed log-in code. It would be helpful to be able to suspend this for this kind of testing.

Comment: i can second this.  this would be very useful.

Comment: What is the exact value of this limit ? How many requests per second?

Comment: Running into this limit as well in dev cycles, would be nice to be able to specify a different limit while in development.

Comment: @EdgardLeal per this doc, looks like the limit is 10 (requests per second)

What I'm confused about is when the limit is lifted. The message just says "Attempt limit exceeded, please try after some time." So I have no idea when to try again.

User authentication operations such as SignUp, InitiateAuth (sign in), and ForgotPassword
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits-soft

Comment: Agreed, Aws should allow this to be configured

Comment: In my testing, I've waited more than 10 minutes after receiving the warning, and I am still unable to get past the error. This seems excessive. Users should be able to know how long until the error will be lifted.

Comment: @9gt53wS were you able to find the exact time?

Comment: in fact, that's bad for developers and QAs that want to test. I am developing an app, and I want to try multiple times if the forgot password flow on my app is correct and working well

Comment: 2 years later same issue... At the very least allow for a developer mode where one can reset the limit and let aws know "hey I'm developing, it's me it's fine"

Answer (score 3):

this is not the exact answer e.g. attempts limit is not configurable for sure.
but still, if you want to test multiple times, you can try different emails e.g. 
if attempts limits exceed for your Email1, you can start attempting with Email2.
Also, note that you can receive the emails for Email1 and Email2 on a single email address e.g suppose your Email1= xyz@gmail.com you can register your Email2 =xyz+1@gmail.com
This way you can receive emails on xyz@gmail.com for both Email1 and Email2

Comment: This sounds cool "Email2 =xyz+1@gmail.com", but how does it work? Is it something to set in different Cognito users (like test@gmail.com, 2nd is test+1@gmail.com and nth is test+(n-1)@gmail.com) or is it (for me uknown) feature of gmail?

Comment: its a feature of Gmail. Different users would be created on Cognito but you will receive the email on the same email address.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito allows 5 `password reset`/`sign-in` attempts.

After the allowed number is exceeded the service starts temporary lockouts with exponentially increasing times.
Here you can find more details on how it happens:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html

Answer (score 1):

### The default lockout behavior is as follows:

> Users can attempt but fail to sign in correctly five times before
> Amazon Cognito temporarily locks them out. Lockout time starts at one
> second and increases exponentially, doubling after each subsequent
> failed attempt, up to about 15 minutes. Amazon Cognito ignores
> attempts to log in during a temporary lockout period, and these
> attempts don't initiate a new lockout period. After a user waits 15
> minutes, Amazon Cognito resets the temporary lockout. This behavior is
> subject to change.
>
> > https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html

#### Workaround solution:

> If resetting password using email , you can use something like guerrillamail to get many new temporary emails to work around the limitExceeded exception.

> If resseting password using phone , try using a virtual phone number provider like google voice to get at least 2 phone-#'s to work around the limitExceeded exception.

The workaround I have used (while testing user confirmation flow) is: once the limit is reached, make sure to complete a correct flow to reset the exponential backoff , then delete account and continue testing after re-creating the account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the dashboard, you can try manually disabling / re-enabling the user.  This worked for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me